# Splitting and returning a data frame in r using a variable and then a sub-variable within the original variable

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to use the `ddply()`function to split and return deuce versus ad points based on my data for tennis. Here is the function I apply:

```
d.ad=function(data){
  data$rownumber=1:nrow(data)
  data$Ad=ifelse(data$rownumber %% 2 == 0, 1, 0)
  data$Deuce=ifelse(data$rownumber %% 2 == 0, 0, 1)

  return(as.data.frame(data))
}
```

Now I want to split and return the data by each match and THEN by game type. For example, I tried putting both variables in the command but it isnt doing what I need. I need the function to be applied to each match, and then within each match to each game.

```
FedvRH=ddply(FedvRH,.(Gm.,match_id),d.ad)
```

This did not work, how do I split it up by the first variable `match_id`, and then within that match variable by the `Gm.` variable? Couldn't find any similar question but maybe I'm not asking it clearly

For example:
[There are different match ID's but all start with Gm. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em5Dj.png) the first game of the match. Newbie to this so didn't know how to get it in other than a quick screenshot.

But I want to get it so it doesn't automatically alternate between Deuce and Ad, that is what is happening now. This is not always the case because some individual games end on a a Deuce side point, so the next game starts with a Deuce side point as well. So I want to split it by `match_id`and then by each `Gm.` within each `match_id` so it alternates Deuce Ad correctly for each `match_id`. If that makes sense, I apologize if it is confusing.

Comment: please provide reproducible data/example.

Comment: Tried to help out and edited it

Comment: Please don't use `$` inside a function.  Use `[[`